# How to update a PWA when has been already installed

Tags: ios, reactjs, progressive-web-apps, mern

so I created a MERN Stack app and convert it to PWA, and install it on my Samsung and iPhone to see how it looks. It works perfectly and even test it with Lighthouse on Chrome. The issue is that I have made some changes in some links and when I delete the cache I can see the changes in my computer, but what happen if a client install it, how they will get the changes if they don't know about them.

Please let me know if there is way to push the changes automatically. The site is [plitz7.com](https://plitz7.com)

Comment: By default, PWA changes are loaded in the background and shown to the user automatically the next time they open the PWA.

Comment: Hey Mathias, that's what I thought but the changes are not happening, so maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Are you leaving the app open for more than a few seconds (to allow background update to happen), closing it, then opening again?

Comment: Hey Mathias, I see. It works, it updates after a while but only on Android. I don't see the changes on iPhone

Comment: I'm Android only, so I don't know what's happening with iOS, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution. I put `var cacheName = "anyname-v1.0.0"` on the first line of my worker.js, then, in caches, I added

```
.open(cacheName)
```

Every time I make changes on any part of my website I change the version of the cache name and voila!

Answer (score 3):

This is how I am doing this in my PWA. Add the next code inside your page, where you register the service worker:

```
<script type="module">


import {Workbox} from 'https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/4.1.0/workbox-window.prod.mjs';

  function createUIPrompt(opts) {
    if (confirm('A new update is available. Do you want to update now?')) {
       opts.onAccept()
    }
  }

  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    const wb = new Workbox('/sw.js');
    wb.addEventListener('waiting', (event) => {
      const prompt = createUIPrompt({
        onAccept: async () => {
          wb.addEventListener('controlling', (event) => {
            window.location.reload();
          });
          wb.messageSW({type: 'SKIP_WAITING'});
        }
      })
    });
    wb.register();
  }
  </script>
```

And then inside your service worker add the next code:

```
self.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
    if (event.data && event.data.type === "SKIP_WAITING") {
        skipWaiting();
    }
});
```

More info about this approach you can find here https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/advanced-recipes#offer_a_page_reload_for_users

Comment: Hi Dmytro, I forgot to change sw.js to the name of my file, I think it will work, will try again and I hope it will work.

Comment: The code works on chrome, but it doesn't on iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue with my pwa app. and I've found one best solution.

Change Version Id after every change and it'll work smoothly.

Add Beginning of Service-worker.js

```
var APP_NAME = <AppName>;
var APP_VER = "1.0";
var CACHE_NAME = APP_NAME + "-" + APP_VER;
```

Add Ending of Service-worker.js

```
self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {

    event.waitUntil(self.clients.claim());
    event.waitUntil(
        //Check cache number, clear all assets and re-add if cache number changed
        caches.keys().then(cacheNames => {
            return Promise.all(
                cacheNames
                    .filter(cacheName => (cacheName.startsWith(APP_NAME + "-")))
                    .filter(cacheName => (cacheName !== CACHE_NAME))
                    .map(cacheName => caches.delete(cacheName))
            );
        })
    );
    if(APP_DIAG){console.log('Service Worker: Activated')}
});
```

Comment: That looks good, I will have test it.